# _strrev way of running

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, function

Can somebody explain what happens at every step in the following code that prints the prefixes of the word "*some*": s so som some ?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {  char s[] = "some";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {   _strrev(s);
        cout << _strrev(s + strlen(s) - i - 1) << " ";
        _strrev(s + strlen(s) - i - 1);
        _strrev(s);
    }

    cin.get();
 }
```

Actually I don't get it how the "*som*" word gets printed ... I know that it's the same code that printed "*s*" and "*so*" but when I get to the next prefix, trying to do this on paper, I get "*smo*".

Comment: calling `strlen(s)` again and again is very inefficient. Why don't store it in a variable?

Comment: I wasn't trying to get something efficient now... just to solve it.

Comment: Be aware that `_strrev` is not standard. It seems to be specific to Microsoft's implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four string inversions. The outer ones (first and fourth) cancel each-other and the inner ones cancel each-other as well.

In fact, this code is doing the following in each iteration:

- inverts the string
- reinverts the substring after the index
- prints the substring out
- inverts the substring
- reinverts the string

Let's see the cycles:

Iteration1:

- some -> emos
- s -> s (emos)
- print s
- s -> s (emos)
- emos -> some

Iteration2:

- some -> emos
- os -> so (emso)
- print so
- so -> os (emos)
- emos -> some

Iteration3:

- some -> emos
- mos -> som (esom)
- print som
- som -> mos
- emos - some

Iteration4:

- some -> emos
- emos -> some
- print some
- some -> emos
- emos -> some